# Mailing Address is forcing 2nd Record in CSV (DevExpress Controls)

Tags: vb.net, csv, devexpress, xtragrid

My DevExpress CSV export has two lines per record.

```
Rank Score,Prog.,Full Address               
63.30     ,JIW  ,1234 Whispering Pines Dr   
          ,     ,Sometown MI 48316
62.80     ,JIW  ,9876 Beagle Dr             
          ,     ,Sometown Twp MI 48382
```

I would like to change it to one line because I want to do a Word Merge. (Unless Word can merge these two lines back together, which I do not thing it can do)

Does the DevExpress **XtraGrid ExportToText** allow for this?

A MemoEdit is being used by the XtraGrid and is initialized using the following code (Noticed the ControlChars.NewLine):

```
Public ReadOnly Property FullAddress() As String
    Get
        Dim strAddress As System.Text.StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
        If Not IsNullEntity Then
            strAddress.Append(Line1 + ControlChars.NewLine)
            If Not Line2 Is Nothing AndAlso Me.Line2.Length > 0 Then
                strAddress.Append(Line2 + ControlChars.NewLine)
            End If
            If Not Line3 Is Nothing AndAlso Me.Line3.Length > 0 Then
                strAddress.Append(Line3 + ControlChars.NewLine)
            End If
            strAddress.Append(String.Format("{0} {1} {2}", City, RegionCode, PostalCode))
            If Me.Country <> "UNITED STATES" Then
                strAddress.Append(ControlChars.NewLine + Me.Country)
            End If
        End If
        Return strAddress.ToString
    End Get
End Property
```

Here is the export to CSV code:

```
    Dim saveFile As New SaveFileDialog
    With saveFile
        '.InitialDirectory = ClientManager.CurrentClient.Entity.StudentPictureDirectory
        .FileName = "ApplicantList.csv"
        .CheckPathExists = True
        .CheckFileExists = False
        .Filter = "All Files (*.*)|*.*"
    End With
    If saveFile.ShowDialog() = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK Then
        Dim PrintingTextExportOptions As New DevExpress.XtraPrinting.TextExportOptions(",", Encoding.ASCII)
        PrintingTextExportOptions.QuoteStringsWithSeparators = True
        ApplicantRankListViewsGridControl.ExportToText(saveFile.FileName, PrintingTextExportOptions)
    End If
```

Answer (score 2):

I have found http://www.filehelpers.net/ to be a great tool for exporting/importing files into different formats.  Hope this helps you out.